# Beautifulsoup gets timeout message

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, telegram

I'm trying to get the search results of a website with beautifulsoup.
The URL is: https://www.wg-gesucht.de/wg-zimmer-in-Muenster.91.0.1.0.html

When you visit the site in your browser, you see the search results without login etc.
However, when i print the the result, I get an error from the website: "
                    Ihre Anfrage scheint abgelaufen zu sein.
                "

```html
"<h4 class="modal-title text-info text-uppercase" id="time_out_modal_label">
                    Ihre Anfrage scheint abgelaufen zu sein.
                </h4>"
```

It then tells you to reload the page and to try again.

```py
def getPage(search_url):
   resp = requests.get(search_url)
   return BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the page via `requests` seems to go normally. When I look at the source there is `Ihre Anfrage scheint abgelaufen zu sein.` modal dialog, but the dialog it's in every request (and hidden in normal browser):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ' https://www.wg-gesucht.de/wg-zimmer-in-Muenster.91.0.1.0.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for headline in soup.select('h3.headline.noprint'):
    print(headline.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
WG Zimmer in perfekter Lage
Möbliertes 17 qm Zimmer direkt am Hafen, zentral
WG-Zimmer in der Innenstadt
WG-Zimmer im Kreuzviertel
Schönes WG-Zimmer zur Zwischenmiete in zentraler Lage
Zimmer frei am Aasee!
Kleines, aber feines möbliertes WG-Zimmer im Zentrum ab dem 01.09
zentrales 14 qm Zimmer frei zur Zwischenmiete bis Oktober
Großes möbliertes Zimmer in 2er WG zur Zwischenmiete
25 m² Zimmer in 3er WG im Zentrum MS
Schönes WG-Zimmer zur Zwischmiete :)
17 qm am Hafen in 4er WG
WG im Gievenbeck zur Untermiete
Möbliertes WG-Zimmer zur Zwischenmiete in TOP Lage
Zwischenmiete einen Monat in 3er WG  Centrums- und Bahnhofsnähe
Perfekt als Übergang zur Wohnungssuche! Möbliertes 18 qm Zimmer für September in netter 3er WG, direkt im Kreuzviertel
WG-Zimmer zur Zwischenmiete in perfekter Lage
Preisgünstiges Zimmer im Kreuzviertel
Helles 22qm-Zimmer in sehr zentraler Berufstätigen-WG
Modernes WG-Zimmer in 4-er WG
```